# Running whole app thru kubernetes while one part is externally deployed

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My question concerns kubernetes set up for the development purposes. The app consosts of 4 services (react + express backend, nginx for routing, neo4j as a db). Neo4J Db is deployed in google cloud (not by me and it is not mantained by me either) but all other services are running now locally as I’m developing the app. What I want to achieve is to start up and run all those services at once, all together with a simple command as it is possible in docker compose world (thru docker-compose up).

Comment: What have you already tried?  Kubernetes can be a little tricky as a development environment, what led you down this path?

Comment: I tried to use docker-compose but this can be tricky as well as neo4j is deployed and I can use it thru kubernetes port-forwarding only. This however is pretty hard to configure as a another docker-compose service

Comment: It's unclear. Are you looking for a production deployment of your app? Or, has something changed requiring you to change how you develop it? If you're looking to continue to develop, you could make the port-forward and then (continue to) use Docker Compose referencing the local port. If you want to move this to production, you could deploy your Docker Compose to e.g. Compute Engine and continue that way?

Comment: Alternatively, it should be relatively straightforward to deploy this to e.g. Kubernetes (Engine) to run it that way too. You'll need to convert the docker-compose.yaml(s) to Kubernetes configuration. See [Kompose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/) as a way to bootstrap this process. The main difference will be that you'll need a GCP (not Kubernetes) service account that permits access to the Neo4J DB and then you'll need to import that service account as a Kubernetes secret so that your Kubernetes deployment may access the DB.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_3_create_service_account_credentials)'s a well-documented example (it uses Pub/Sub but the principle applies to any service running on GCP) of importing a GCP service account to be used by a Kubernetes Deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Just few words of clarification. I'm not thinking about deploying it yet. What I need now is just to run all in development. It would be perfect that while being in development I could use deployed Neo4j DB. This is deployed in google cloud and available through port forwarding (run with kubectl).